# flash fallback in jplayer not working in firefox 16 and opera 12

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jplayer

I'm making a music website for which i'm using jplayer..the player works just fine in chrome but fails in all other browsers..all my browsers are up-to date. my flash player is upto-date too. the current version being flash player 11.4. i went through the jplayer documentation but didn't help. so here's my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    var url1,url2;
                    $('.singles').click(function(event){
                        var x = event.target;
                        var y = x.replace(".mp3",".oga");
                        url1 = "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/songs/"+x.innerHTML;
                        url2 = "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/songs/"+y;
                        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia",{
                            mp3: url1,
                            oga: url2
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    });
                },
                swfPath: "/jPlayer/Jplayer.swf",
                solution: "html/flash",
                supplied: "mp3, oga",
                wmode: "window"
            });
        });
```

i added the some code for oga because i was told firefox and opera require oga and not mp3 to be supplied. the same problem persisted even before adding the code for oga

i see the following text on top of jplayer:
Update Required
To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your Flash plugin.

what should i do?? please help

Answer (score 1):

I think it's about the path to swf file. You're not supposed to put the filename in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The solution options should be comma-separated instead of /-separated.